# Problema com cadastro usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou criando um sistema simples de cadastro em PDO (sou iniciante nisto), e, não estou tendo sucesso na elaboração da minha string de conexão e no ajuste do INSERT para adicionar dados ao banco.

Dá o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: PDO in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/KELVYN/Novo/cadastro_2.php on line 23

## Arquivo de conexão.php

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "");
define("BD", "kelvyn");

try{

    $conecta    = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD, USER, PASS);

}catch(PDOException $e){

    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

## Arquivo cadastro_2.php

```
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

if(!empty($dados)){

if($conecta){

    #$erro  = "Ocorreu o Seguinte erro: ".mysql_error()." | Código do erro: ".mysql_errno();
    $query  = "INSERT INTO clientes(cliente,cpf,idt,data,plano,vencimento,endereco,bairro,cidade,estado,cep,login,senha,email,tel_fixo,tel_cel,referencia,aceita_termos_contrato,obs) VALUES (:cliente,:cpf,:idt,:data,:planos,:vencimento,:endereco,:bairro,:cidade,:estado,:cep,:login,:senha,:email,:tel_fixo,:tel_cel,:referencia,:aceito-contrato)";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam( ':cliente', $dados["cliente"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':cpf', $dados["cpf"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':idt', $dados["idt"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':data', $dados["data"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':plano', $dados["plano"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':vencimento', $dados["vencimento"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':endereco', $dados["endereco"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':bairro', $dados["bairro"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':cidade', $dados["cidade"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':estado', $dados["estado"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':cep', $dados["cep"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':login', $dados["login"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':senha', $dados["senha"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':email', $dados["email"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':tel_fixo', $dados["tel_cel"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':referencia', $dados["referencia"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':aceita_termos_contrato', $dados["aceita_termos_contrato"] );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':obs', $dados["obs"] );

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if(!$result){
        var_dump( $stmt->errorInfo() );
        exit;
        #header("location: thanks.php");
    }
    header("location: thanks.php");
}

}
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo a Rede SOpt, sugiro que faça um [tour] antes de mais nada :)
Poderia indicar qual a linha 23?

Comment: Possivelmente, seu erro esteja aqui: `$stmt = $PDO->prepare($query);`
mude para `$stmt = $conecta->prepare($query);`

Comment: Caro Amigo, agradeço imensamente! Foi isso mesmo. Linha 23 era este $PDO mesmo. Resolveu, porém tive outro problema agora. 

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/KELVYN/Novo/cadastro_2.php on line 43

Esta linha é isso aqui:
$result = $stmt->execute();

Comment: Nos seus `VALUES`, falta `:obs`

Comment: Muito obrigado! Identifiquei uma serie de erros que cometi.
Ainda estou tendo problemas. Mesmo assim, gostei muito de PDO.

Comment: Consegui resolver todos os problemas! Muito Obrigado, amigo!